Can I plug in numbers for x when proving limits?
At what point can I plug in values for x when proving limits? I know I can't have delta be a function of X. I also know delta should be epsilon divided by 9, but am I allowed to just start plugging in numbers?
I guess I'm confused because if I just plug in x = 5 then |x - 5| would not be > 0.


"I also know delta should be epsilon divided by 9 ..." How do you know this?

@DavidK I guess I don't know that

Here you would make an assumption on how close $x$ is to 5. This will bound $|x+4|$ and allow you to replace it with a constant in the inequality. Try assuming $|x-5|<1$, i.e. $-1<x-5<1$.

@DavidP Thanks, I'll give that shot

I perceive a possible underlying issue.  If you are in the middle of a math course, and this is a math problem from that math course, then I suspect that you have a workflow problem.  What I mean by this is that I suspect that you do not have a solid intuitive grasp on the concepts that have been taught so far, in the class.  ...see next comment

As I see it you have three choices, none of which you are going to like: [1] Try to struggle through the class through memorization, and hope to somehow pass the final exam, or get extra credit by doing extra problems, so that the teacher will show you grading mercy. [2] Inform your teacher that you have (in effect) gone off the rails with respect to actually learning the concepts, and ask the teacher for guidance as you go back to page 1.  Ask the teacher for special exercises that will ensure a solid grasp of the material on one page, before moving on to the next page....see next comment

[3] Drop the course.

I'm not in a class. I graduated 10 years ago. I'm just interested in learning real analysis. I thought I understood the definition of a limit but I guess not. @user2661923

Since this is not a class, at least there is not the kind of time pressure you would have in that environment. Many people have trouble understanding limits at first. If you can master the mechanics of them now, you may find that after you've gone a little further into real analysis, when you look back at the definition of a derivative it will seem more intuitive.

Make sure you understand the meaning of the $\varepsilon-\delta$ formulation of limit. The idea is that there exists some tolerance $\delta > 0$ on the input $x$ away from $x_0 = 5$ which achieves an arbitrarily set tolerance $\varepsilon > 0$ on $f (x) = x^2 - x - 1$ away from $L = 19$. The value of $\delta$ is allowed to vary with the given $\varepsilon$.
If $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently large, then we can pick some fixed value of $\delta$ to ensure that $0 < d (x, x_0) < \delta \implies d (f (x), L) < \varepsilon$. For your problem, you should try to show that for any $\varepsilon \ge 10$, picking $\delta = 1$ satisfies that $0 < d (x, 5) < \delta \implies d (f (x), 19) < \varepsilon$.
Now, we turn to cases where $\varepsilon < 10$. If you think about the behavior of $f (x)$ near $x = x_0$, you will find that it is (1) monotonically increasing, and (2) increases faster to the right of $x = x_0$ than from the left. So, we should select $\delta$ such that
$$f (x_0 + \delta) - L \le \varepsilon$$
Substituting the function, and noting $f (x_0) - L = 0$, we obtain
$$\delta^2 + (2 x_0 - 1) \delta - \varepsilon \le 0$$
For $x_0 = 5$ and $\delta > 0$, this implies
$$\delta \le \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{4 \varepsilon + 81} - 9 \right)$$
You can show that for $0 < \varepsilon < 10$, we in fact have
$$\frac{1}{10} \varepsilon < \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{4 \varepsilon + 81} - 9 \right)$$
so taking $\delta = \frac{1}{10} \varepsilon$ (for $\varepsilon < 10$) suffices.
EDIT
Alternatively, your derivation also works for the second case (sufficiently small $\varepsilon$). Note that
$$|x - 5| < \delta \implies |x + 4| = |x - (-4)| < 9 + \delta$$
Therefore, it suffices to make
$$\delta |x + 4| < \delta (9 + \delta) \le \varepsilon$$
$$\implies \delta^2 + 9 \delta - \varepsilon \le 0$$
which is exactly the same inequality obtained above (since $2 x_0 - 1 = 2 (5) - 1 = 9$).
